# ¿Como saber en Python si los elementos en una lista son diferentes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Quiero saber como puedo hacer para verificar que los elementos de una lista son todos diferentes (ninguno repetido).

Ej:

```
lista=[1,-1,1,3,9,5]
codigo_verificador()
```

Salida:

```
True # Hay un elemento repetido
```

¿Como puedo saber que hay elementos repetidos?
Ya intente usar un código asi :

Las letras son números que pone el usuario

```
 lista = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h]
 if ar != br and br!=cr and cr!=dr and dr!=er and er != fr and fr!=gr and 
 gr!=hr and ass!=bs and bs!=cs and cs!=ds and ds!=es and es!=fs and fs!=gs and 
 gs!=hs:
 print("Todos son diferentes")
```

Pero aun así no me sale :c

Comment: Hola! bienvenido a SO. porfavor trata de formatear tu código para hacerlo más legible. adicionalmente te recomiendo como concejo que no uses como tag ambas versiones de python, en este caso es redundante. usa solo el de la versión que estas usando para obtener respuesta una más precisa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Que 'a' no sea igual a 'b' y que 'b' no sea igual a 'c' no significa que 'a' no sea igual a 'c'. Hacer todas las posibles comparaciones en la lista de esa forma no escala, y en cuanto cambie el tamaño de la lista ya no serviría.

Una solución muy simple es convertir tu lista en un set, en el cuál no puede haber valores repetidos. Compara el tamaño de tu lista con el del set y si son iguales es que todos son diferentes.

```
lista=[1,-1,1,3,9,5]
if len(lista)==len(set(lista)): # False porque hay dos '1'
    print 'Todos son diferentes'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternativamente a la opción que dio el compañero [javdr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/103383/javrd) puedes usar bucles `for` anidados, donde el primer `for` vaya recorriendo elementos de la lista, y en el segundo `for` que vaya comparándolos con los elementos del primer `for`, para entenderlo mejor, ejemplifico:

```
numeros = [1,-1,1,3,9,5]
def comparar(lista):
    indice_c = -1   # Se asigna a 0 para que no de error al comparar el index en el for
    for elemento in lista:
        indice_c = -1
        indice = lista.index(elemento)  # Se asigna el numero de indice del elemento a comparar
        for comparacion in lista: # Se toma el elemento a comparar
            indice_c += 1
            if indice_c == indice: # Esto es para evitar que se confunda el programa y compare un
                                   # elemento consigo mismo, lo cual no tendria sentido

                continue # Se reinicia el bucle
            elif elemento == comparacion: # Si el elemento de la lista es igual al elemento 
                                          # comparado, se retorna un False
                return False
    return True # De no haber elementos iguales, se retorna un True
print (comparar(numeros))
```

Salida con elemento repetido

```
# numeros = [1,-1,1,3,9,5]
False
```

Salida, ahora sin elemento repetido:

```
# numeros = [1,-1,3,9,5]
True
```

Si no lo entiendes, puedes usar Visual Studio Code para debuggear el código y ver las variables en tiempo real.

Claramente, la opción que te dio [javdr](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/103383/javrd) es mucho mas **simple y elegante**, pero te doy
esta alternativa de todas formas.

***Saludos***